# Graceful stop of Jetty/Jersey with running async requests handlers

Tags: java, servlets, asynchronous, jersey, jetty

I'm running an embedded Jetty [+ Jersey] and using async requests handlers (https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/async.html#d0e8742).

When I'm stopping jetty via server.stop() it

a) first shut down the connectors thus not accepting new connections anymore and then

b) wait for active *syncronous* handlers to be finished or for timeout, then

c) all remaining connections are simply closed.

In async request handler I'm using an executor (thread pool) to do real processing.

So, the question: How to stop my executor between a) and b), i.e. how to make jetty wait for async requests to finish as well?

Is there any other way to do a graceful shutdown for Jetty using async handlers?

Comment: I like to use the Spring ThreadPoolTaskExecutor http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ExecutorConfigurationSupport.html#setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown-boolean- http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html

Comment: @DavidW Still cannot grasp how to use this pool together with jetty so I get correct shutdown sequence

Comment: sorry I don't know Jetty well enough to help. You could look to this https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Spring with a goal of making ThreadPoolTaskExecutor a bean